# What is the best approach I can follow to read list items which represent a setting list for our event receivers

Tags: 2013, development, event-receivers, splistitem

I am working on building many event receivers inside my SharePoint 2013 enterprise server. and i created a list to store all the settings and variables that will be used inside the event receivers.

Now i wrote the following code to read the settings values inside my event receivers :-

```
 DataTable currentTempleteSettings = properties.Site.RootWeb.GetList(properties.Site.RootWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Lists/ServiceManualTemplateSettings/").Items.GetDataTable();
string termstorename = "";
                    string groupname = "";
                    string contenttype = "";
                    string pagelayout = "";
                    foreach (DataRow splistitem in currentTempleteSettings.Rows)//build the variables based on the TemplateSetting List
                    {
                        if (splistitem["Title"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() as string == "group")
                            groupname = splistitem["SettingValue"] as string;


                        else if (splistitem["Title"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() as string == "contenttype")
                            contenttype = splistitem["SettingValue"] as string;

                        else if (splistitem["Title"].ToString().ToLower().Trim() as string == "pagelayout")
                            pagelayout = splistitem["SettingValue"] as string;

                      //code goes here for other 6 settings!!
                    }
```

This is working well, but I am not sure if there is a better way to implement this settings.

Is there?

Comment: The only enhancement I can think of is using switch case instead of if else.. rest seems fine

Comment: If security is the case (like if you're storing sensitive information), you can use list property bag instead. That way, even if the account that can access the list is compromised, a person would need to have access to the server (and PowerShell) to see the information on the list. In most cases it's an overkill, tho :)